# How to add a default filter parameter to every query in mongoengine?

Tags: mongoengine

I've been researching a lot, but I haven't found a way.
I have `Document` clases with a `_owner` attribute which specifies the `ObjectID` of the owner, which is a per-request value, so it's globally available. I would like to be able to set part of the query by default.

For example, doing this query

```
MyClass.objects(id='12345')
```

should be the same as doing

```
MyClass.objects(id='12345', _owner=global.owner)
```

because `_owner=global.owner` is always added by default

I haven't found a way to override `objects`, and using a `queryset_class`is someway confusing because I still have to remember to call a "`.owned()`" manager to add the filter every time I want to query something.

It ends up like this...

```
MyClass.objects(id='12345').owned() 
// same that ...
MyClass.objects(id='12345', _owner=global.owner)
```

Any Idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick for querying (example is simplified by using a constant `owned=True` but it can easily be extended to use your global):

```py
class OwnedHouseWrapper(object):
    # Implements descriptor protocol

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return House.objects.filter(owned=True)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise Exception("can't set .objects")


class House(Document):
    address = StringField()
    owned = BooleanField(default=False)

class OwnedHouse:
    objects = OwnedHouseWrapper()

House(address='garbage 12', owned=True).save()
print(OwnedHouse.objects())    # [<House: House object>]
print(len(OwnedHouse.objects)) # 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I already tried that way but `objects` is an obj itself. I can’t do for example `len(OwnedHouse.objects)` but I can do `len(House.objects)`, so this solution breaks compatibility with other libraries or components :/

Comment: I've edited my answer, its possible to improve the previous solution by using the descriptor protocol